# Intel Integrated graphics GDM leaves ghosts/leftovers (also in gnome shell)

Tags: intel-graphics, gnome-shell, gdm

I'm using an updated version of Arch linux, and get constant ghosts on GDM + Gnome Shell.

Here is an example:

[image]

I tried both modsetting and intel driver.

I tried DRI 3 and 2

I tried SNA and UXA

I tried the TearFree option

and also:

i915.enable_rc6=0 i915.enable_psr=0 i915.modset=0 intel.modset=0

And this unwanted behavior keeps showing.

I'll be happy to get help on this one, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So currently the ghosts at GDM and Gnome-Shell stopped when i commented out:

```
# /etc/environment
CLUTTER_PAINT=disable-clipped-redraws:disable-culling
```

As described here:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wa … nd_crashes

Apparently it was a Wayland vs X11 issue.